# Generate observations from a DGP autoregressive process? R or Stata

Tags: r, statistics, stata

I'm wondering how I could go about generating data from an AR process yt=0.2+0.5yt-1 +et 
where et~N(0,1) with y1=0.2

I need to generate 100 observations from t2 to t100

I need to do this in either R or Stata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be pretty much a direct translation in R

```
y <- numeric( length=100)
y[1] <- 0.2
et <- rnorm(100)
for( t in 2:100)
  { y[t] = 0.2 + 0.5*y[t-1] +et[t] }
```

For reproducibility put `set.seed(num)` in front where num is an integer and to do it 100 or 1000 times, put it inside a `replicate` call.

```
plot(y)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi BondedDust, I tried that code in R and it doesn't seem to be working. My R skills are a little rusty, is there any advice you could offer?

Comment: My fault. Three syntactic errors corrected. Should succeed now.